# How to hide the "Google Games" Fragment on connect

Tags: android

While this seems like something that is definitely possible, I'm stumped.

Basically, I want to get rid of the below dialog that automatically appears when calling `connect` on my `GoogleApiClient`. Since `connect` is async, I'd like to do move along with my own UI while waiting for this callback, rather than watch this one.

[image: Google Play Games Overlay]

My only thought so far was to do try and hide the view like such, but I assume this must not be the "popup" in question, because it didn't work:

```
mGooglePlayApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .setViewForPopups(findViewById(R.id.invisView))
            .build();
```

I am using Play Services 9.2.0.

Comment: I would be careful stepping on Googles Toes. That sort of thing might be required under TOS. That said I am not a lawyer. That said if you take it out you 100% will Never be featured in the google play store.

Comment: I'm more trying to understand if this is even possible, rather than try than get around a requirement.

Comment: My guess is that it is not. Maybe on a rooted device. That said all things are possible and I would start looking at reflection / ways to intercept the raw views and hide by their IDs..